# How to use the session from passportjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local

I am able to login using passport-local. I want to test if the session created by passport is valid. I am logging in from Angular. When the user logs in, i dont create any manual cookie but see a `connect.sid` cookie is created. Now from Angular I'm sending another `req`:

```
$scope.test = function(){
    $http.get('\test').then(function(response){
        if(response){
            console.log(response);
        } else {
            console.log("Nothing Returned!");
        }
    });
}
```

And in node :

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));


//Passport Init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
         done(err, user);
    });
});


app.get('\test', function(req, res){

   //Tried the following (one at a time) : 
    var user = req.user;
    var user = req[user];
    var user = req["user"];
    var user = req.session;

    console.log(user);
    res.send(user);

});
```

None of the above works. I get res code 200 but nothing in `response.data` in Angular and nothing in `undefined` in node console.

Im doing this cause I think :

1. After user logs in, Passportjs creates session is persisted until its destroyed by logout.
2. After user logs in, there is no need to create a cookie and send it to Angular. Passport does this automatically.
3. When Angular sends any request, node can access the session of `req` and verify with it's own session.

Am I correct with all these 3 points?

Many thanks!

**EDIT**
My mongoose schema:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id : {type:String, default:"abc123"},
    username: {type:String, index: true},
    password: String,
    email: {type:String, unique:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**EDIT 2**
Adding output that i get when placed the `express session` before `passport session`

[image]

**EDIT 3**
My strategy :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, doc){
            if(err) {
                // console.log(err);
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, doc);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: Maybe it's something with your passport configuration, put a snippet of your passport code.

Comment: Added to the OP. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order, put 'express session' before 'passport session'. It should work this way:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

http://passportjs.org/docs/configure

Comment: Please check `EDIT1`.  Changed the order and im getting something with `var user = req.session;` It contains a basic cookie information and no `id`. I don't think this is enough information to reply upon.

Comment: According to the [passport website](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure): "Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use express.session() before passport.session() to ensure that the login session is restored in the correct order."

I tried your code and it works, the only thing I don't see is how you configure your `passport-local` strategy.

Comment: My `passport-local` is the default one. I defined `LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;` How are you accessing the session? Is it `req.user`/`req["user"]`/`req.session` ?

Comment: Can you please share your code? In a plunker or something please

Comment: You need to configure the strategy. Take a look at this: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#configure-strategy. You also need a route to authenticate the username/password (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#authenticate-requests). The authenticated user is in `req.user`.

Comment: Added my strategy. Please check `EDIT 3` What is the output you're getting? Please share the output.

Comment: I'm only checking for the username in the `Strategy`. That is doing the job of logging the `doc` in console. But i cant get the session `id` or any info of the user.

Comment: What is the output if you log `user` in `serializeUser` and `id` in `deserializeUser`? My `req.user` object has `id, username, email, and password` properties and `req.session` is the same as yours but with another property: `passport: { user: 'id-of-the-user' }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138886/discussion-between-somename-and-luisenrike).

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling passport.initialize() and passport.session() ?
passport.session is the call that reads the cookie and stores user in req object.

Check this answer for more details: [What does passport.session() middleware do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052258/what-does-passport-session-middleware-do)

Comment: Edited my question. Please check.

Comment: You should add a log to serializeUser and deserializeUser. My guess is that if you are using mongodb, the id is stored as _id. So in serializeUser, it should be done(null, user._id)

Comment: You're right. I'm using mongodb. But my document does have an `id` field. I edited my question to show the `user schema`. Thanks.