# what is passport.initialize()? (nodejs express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, passport.js, node-modules

I'm now trying to apply passport module in my apps.

I'm reading some manuals, and there say,

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

what is `app.use(passport.initialize())` exactly doing?

`passport.session()` is maybe for the passport to use the session information,

But I have no idea about the `passport.initialize()`

Comment: A related issue on Github: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/868#issuecomment-1632433930

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`passport.initialize()` is a middle-ware that initialises [Passport](http://passportjs.org/docs).

[Middlewares](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle.

Passport is an authentication middleware for Node that authenticates requests.

So basically `passport.initialize()` initialises the authentication module.

`passport.session()` is another middleware that alters the request object and change the 'user' value that is currently the session id (from the client cookie) into the true deserialized user object. [It is explained in detail here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28994045/1740715)

Answer (score 28):

Sometimes it's better to look into the code: [passport github on initialize()](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/2327a36e7c005ccc7134ad157b2f258b57aa0912/lib/middleware/initialize.js)

**TL;DR**

With sessions, `initialize()` setups the functions to serialize/deserialize the user data from the request.

You **are not required** to use `passport.initialize()` if you are not using `sessions`.

```js
/**
 * Passport initialization.
 *
 * Intializes Passport for incoming requests, allowing authentication strategies
 * to be applied.
 *
 * If sessions are being utilized, applications must set up Passport with
 * functions to serialize a user into and out of a session.  For example, a
 * common pattern is to serialize just the user ID into the session (due to the
 * fact that it is desirable to store the minimum amount of data in a session).
 * When a subsequent request arrives for the session, the full User object can
 * be loaded from the database by ID.
 *
 * Note that additional middleware is required to persist login state, so we
 * must use the `connect.session()` middleware _before_ `passport.initialize()`.
 *
 * If sessions are being used, this middleware must be in use by the
 * Connect/Express application for Passport to operate.  If the application is
 * entirely stateless (not using sessions), this middleware is not necessary,
 * but its use will not have any adverse impact.
...
```

Comment: Hi there, is it really true that you are not required to use passport.initialize() when using JWT tokens for example?

Comment: @FabianBosler `passport.initialize()` is related to the use of `session` or not, so it depends on the way you are implementing the JWT authentication. At the moment I can't tell you more than this.

Comment: Your answer solves my curiousity, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From the Passportjs documentation:

> In a Connect or Express-based application, passport.initialize()
>   middleware is required to initialize Passport. If your application
>   uses persistent login sessions, passport.session() middleware must
>   also be used.

If we have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/initialize.js), we can see that passport.initialize() middleware basically add passport instance to incoming requests so that authentication strategy can be proceed.
If there is a session, it is added to requests as well.