# What does passport.initialize() do?

Tags: passport.js

Neither passport.js, nor passport-local docs mention passport.initialize(). Is it deprecated? Can anyone post a link to the proper documentation?

Comment: +1. I also wonder why `passport.initialize()` is absent in the current documentation while `req.login()`, which is enabled by `passport.initialize()`, is present.

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/cfdbd4a762b51e339ebfea931d65bccbbde53282/lib/middleware/initialize.js#L7

Comment: First result in Google for "passportjs initialize" is duplicate of this question [what is passport.initialize()? (nodejs express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644366/what-is-passport-initialize-nodejs-express)

Comment: Does this mean that it is impossible to improve this question? What can I do than to be able to ask questions again?